# Moving to an adventure without entering

Tags: elder-sign-omens

Is it possible to move a player to an adventure without entering it and finish its turn?

The help says:

> Investigators begin the game at the Museum Entrance. On their turn the
>   following must be done:
>
> - Move to the Entrance or Adventure
> - Resolve the Adventure or perform an action at the Entrance.

However, the only way I found is to begin an adventure and fail it. Which is quite frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot. The answer is actually in your quote:

> *Resolve the Adventure* or perform an action at the Entrance.

(emphasis mine).

Resolving the adventure requires you to try and complete it. What you should do is try to find an adventure which your investigator is likely to succeed at, or alternatively something with a lower number of symbols to complete. This is how the board game functions as well.